# What is the difference between return render and return HttpResponse in Django?

Tags: django-views

I want to know difference between

```
return (request,"<h1>Hello</h1>")
```

and

```
return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello</h1>")
```

The above sample code is in my views.py file
in Django 1.9 Python 2.7 version. I searched on internet and unable to resolve this.

Comment: Resolve this? is it a problem or you want more understanding of what they do?

Comment: Apologies, I want to understand the difference between these two and when to use which one.